# VPN Connection only for specific service or port

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, vnc, vps

I rented a Virtual Machine and I want to use a VPN Service inside for privacy like Hidemyass & Co.

I connect to the VM via VNC, but every time I switch on the VPN in the VM the VNC connection fails. I use PPTP as VPN.

Is there an easy way to exclude VNC from the VPN. There are a few computers that will connect to the VM so excluding single IPs would also work, but I prefer the VNC or Port solution.

I'm a noob in routing so I need a pretty finished answer.

Comment: VPNs tend to be 'all or nothing' kind of routes.  The exception are VPNs configured such that the default route for the system is *not* via the VPN.  It sounds like you want the inverse - to have everything go over the VPN *except* for certain services.  The Linux routing system does not give you the flexibility to actually have that kind of fine-grained control.

Answer (score 0):

In following script you can add host/route witch is routed to vpn.
The rest of traffic will be going to default gateway

```
#!/bin/bash
function routeadd {
    route add -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ppp0
    route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx dev ppp0
}
function makepptp {
   echo pty \"pptp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --nolaunchpppd\" >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo remotename PPTP >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo require-mppe-128 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo file /etc/ppp/options.pptp >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo ipparam vpn >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
pppd call vpn &
}
if [ -a /etc/ppp/chap-secrets ];
        then
        rm /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
    echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
else
    echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
fi

if [ -e /etc/ppp/peers/vpn ];
    then
    rm /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    makepptp;
    sleep 8;
    routeadd;
else
    echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    makepptp;
    sleep 8;
    routeadd;
fi
```

Usage:

```
sudo /path_to_script/vpn username password
```

note: set execute permision to script

Traffic is routed via vpn only if you add route, anything else go default gw.

Edit 1

In function routeadd you can change

```
function routeadd {
        route add -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ppp0
        route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx dev ppp0
    }
```

to

```
function routeadd {
        route add -host ip_address_for_vnc dev eth0
        route add default dev ppp0
    }
```

This will route vnc traffic to specific ip address to eth0 int and all other to ppp0 int.
Try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i want the opposite.

Everything should go through the PPTP VPN Connection except VNC.

So i want add the VNC Port 5900 to the exception list, and any other traffic through the other ports goes through the PPTP Connection